# Bezier curve taper on independent axes?

Tags: bezier-curves, scale, axis

In the simplified example below I have a straight bezier curve with a bezier circle specified as its bevel object to give a cylinder. I've added a taper object to vary the cylinder's width along its length.

[image: Simple taper example]

I would really like the taper to vary independently across the horizontal and vertical axes, like this:

[image: Independent axis taper]

This doesn't seem to be possible since there's only one Taper object option, and no way to lock it to an axis as there is with the Simple Deform modifier. What would be the best way to do this? I suspect I would have to convert the object to a mesh and then scale by hand with proportional editing, but I'd really like to continue using curves because it'll be easier to get things accurate. Might this be possible, or are there other ways this could be done?

Comment: You could use a Lattice, it works with bezier, but is it the kind of tool you want to use or are you trying to find a 100% bezier solution?

Comment: Ah yes, that should do the job and give me the fine control I'm looking for. Being able to apply the lattice to the curves will give me the best of both worlds. If you make this an Answer I'll give you some StackExchange points :)

Comment: can also use bones and scale them to have the taper effect.

Comment: @ lemon, could you please tell a bit more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a *Lattice* modifier, it works fine with beveled bezier (just keep in mind that when you create your lattice, adapt its size to the object in *Object* mode, not in *Edit* mode):

[image]